# Connect remote session through aws instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two connected sessions to my aws ami instance one from home and the other from work at the same, `who -u` shows both sessions, now is there a way I connect to my work session from home through aws instance?

```
[root@ip-172-31-18-50 ~]# who -u
ec2-user pts/0        2016-10-11 06:07 00:27       26988 (79.170.50.34)
ec2-user pts/1        2016-10-11 06:23   .         27077 (79.170.50.43)
[root@ip-172-31-18-50 ~]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes ofcourse, you can. You can use your EC2 Instance as NAT to do your job.

- you can Use port forwarding and connect to your work session from
  Home via your EC2 instance. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57721/how-to-forward-a-port-from-one-machine-to-another
- Open up security groups of your EC2 Instance and NACLs in your AWS
  VPC to allow traffic to connect to your Work Session.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule

But, I still donot understand why you want to do this. Anyways, hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Good. please mark it as answered if it solved your problem.